# Ants in my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I recently purchased an iPhone 5s (I was on a budget) and lately I have been observing something weird. Know the SIM card hole where you insert a key and open? Ants randomly come from that. They are the smaller variety. I must have killed 20 of them by now.

Will this be fatal for my iPhone? Is there any way to shoo them away?

Comment: Update--one ant comes out every 5 mins!! I observed this for half an hour!!!

Comment: This is some kind of 2k17 revenge bug of [Ant Smasher Christmas](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ant-smasher-christmas-a-free-game-by-the-best-cool-fun-games/id488305689?mt=8). Please either update or uninstall the app. ;-)

Comment: @klanomath Dude I'm serious

Comment: You should file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Leave the SIM card slot open and set up some sugary traps nearby to lure them away. Also let gravity work its way, by placing your phone vertically and connect the trap(s) with some branch-like way for the ants to follow along. [The most effective way however would be, to take your phone apart and brush them out] GL

Comment: @v2r thanks bro, now the ants stopped coming as I killed them one by one as they came out. Let's hope no ant is hiding inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this is *sooo* far off topic that I can see it coming back round from the other side of the page...

However, Pharaoh ants are about the only ones small enough to be doing what you describe. They love to live in small, warm places. They have an interesting method to combat being eradicated either by poisons or crushing. As soon as they feel they're under stress, the colony will bud, sending off new colonies to breed elsewhere.

So, this isn't a problem for your phone - put the phone in a plastic bag with a tiny squirt of ant poison spray. Seal the bag, bye bye ants.

Your *real* problem will be... where are all the others?
There's little chance a small colony like that will be the only one in your home, & no chance that a can of bug spray can eradicate the rest.
You need bait food to get rid of the others.

Have a read about how much 'fun' it can be trying to get rid of them - https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/phar.htm